# Protractor: Find Element by Attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, protractor

I have the following element i need to find for testing:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="notValid">Zugangsdaten eingeben</div>
```

How can i find this element to check visibility (ng-show)?

The ng-show attribute  and value are the only attribute and value to identify the element uniquely. The class is used in many elements...

I am searching for something like:

```
var notValid = element(by.Attribute('ng-show', 'notValid');
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can find it [`by.css()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css):

```
element(by.css('div[ng-show=notValid]'));
$('div[ng-show=notValid]');  // shortcut for the above expression
```

Or, [`by.xpath()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@ng-show="notValid"]'));
```

Comment: I am really sure I tried this and it did not work...But you are right, i did it again and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: this worked for me: `element(by.css('[dummyKey="dummyValue"]'))` i.e I needed the quotes around `dummyValue`