# How to locate element by type, value or alt attribute in protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor

Example 1:
I have this html code for a button.

```
<button class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="LoginCtrl.loginStatus === LoginCtrl.loginCtrlConfig.LOGIN_LOADING">
```

Using protractor, if I don't want to use class name, but use 'type' or 'value' parameter.

Example 2:

```
<img src="someSource" alt="Firewall for Code" width="90" height="46">
```

I want to use the 'alt' parameter for the above img to test that this element is located on the page, hence the test should pass.

How do I achieve above two tasks in Protractor?

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: This possible duplicate contains several ways of locating the element, by either css or xpath [**Protractor: Find Element by Attribute**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826579/protractor-find-element-by-attribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could/should be using [CSS selectors](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css) to add filter conditions on the element attributes.

In the first example, it might be:

```
var submitButton = element(by.css("button[type=submit][value=Login]"));

// element is present
expect(submitButton.isPresent()).toBe(true);

// element is displayed
expect(submitButton.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

In the second example, it would be:

```
var sourceImage = element(by.css('img[alt="Firewall for Code"]'));

// element is present
expect(sourceImage.isPresent()).toBe(true);

// element is displayed
expect(sourceImage.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

Note that in this case, we need quotes around the attribute value since there are spaces in the attribute value. Here is more information about when would you need quotes and then would not:

- [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)